# Changing the font style of line numbers in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, word-processing, numbering

I added line numbers to my document in Microsoft Word 2007. How can I change the font style of these line numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just figured out how to do this.

Essentially, line numbers are assigned a style, just like almost any other special formating in Word.

---

### Process

1. Go to the Home tab of the Ribbon after enabling line numbering.
2. Under Styles, click the Dialog Box Launcher arrow to open the Styles pane.
3. In the Styles pane, click Options.
4. Under "Select styles to show" in the Options window, select "All styles". Under "Select how list is sorted", select "Alphabetical"; this option makes it easier to locate the style in question.
5. Click OK to exit out of the Options window.
6. Back in the Styles pane, scroll down until you find the Style that is called "Line Number". Click the arrow next to it, hit Modify, and change formatting as necessary in the window that opens. Click OK once you're finished and then close the Styles pane.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an option to modify the font of *only* the line numbers, but I've found they assume whatever font you set in the "Normal" style. So if you change the Normal style's font the line numbers will change, but it may upset other styles used in the document.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I just found a way to get around that.